# The most effective way to Imitate an Arduino loop within MatLab

Tags: matlab, loops, arduino

I'm fairly new to interfacing the Arduino into MatLab and I was wondering the most effective way to imitate an Arduino sketch?  More specifically the `loop()` function with the `delay()` function.

For example, if I wanted an infinite loop would I use a `while` loop with the condition `i > 0` providing that `i = 1`?  In addition to this, how would I implement a delay?

Also, does MatLab have an equivalent function to Arduino's `millis()`, as I use an alternative method named "using `millis()` instead of `delay()`" in quite a few of my sketches to create delays.

Or, is it more effective to communicate from the Arduino to MatLab using serial?

My rational for using the Arduino with MatLab is to start plotting real-time graphs with my sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a infinite loop combined with delay, a `timer` with a fixed rate probably matches your requirements.